# What "workers" really are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, resque, unicorn, worker

I feel lost.

**Nginx** has it's own "*Worker*" processes,

**Unicorn** has it's own "*Worker*" settings,

**Resque** has it's own "*Workers*".

Unicorn's settings should be related to Nginx's or Resque's I guess?

I really searched for a clue but didn't got any.

Are all of these "*workers*" same?

If not can you briefly tell what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx - Nginx is the web server that gets the incoming requests and serves to unicorns on request. 
Unicorn - Each unicorn worker loads a separate Rails environment(Worker).
Resque - Each Resque worker loads a separate Rails environment(Worker).

The purpose of Unicorn and Resque are different.
**Unicorn serves the web requests.**
**Resque gets background jobs from Redis and processes it**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder what am I actually setting inside nginx.conf which is named worker_process ? And what am I setting at unicorn.rb inside my app? :s

Comment: Nginx workers processes : http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#worker_processes, Each process forms a request queue to serve the unicorn(which is the rails app). Nginx we put infront of unicorns to serve request when the unicorn is ready. When all unicorns are busy, nginx holds the requests in its queue. Once a unicorn is free, unicorn requests for a process and nginx serves it. Nginx workers is the workers that redirects request to unicorn(rails app). What we specify in unicorn.rb is the number of rails environments

Comment: The term "workers" is actually pretty generic. What you need to understand is `nginx workers != unicorn workers != resque workers` however, a "worker" pretty much means the same thing in all those three. It handles requests. In the case of Resque however, it handles the background processes.

Comment: @Srikanth Thank you for your detailed answers. I think it starts to get clarified to me. However, can you recommend me any nice resources to understand deeply all of these chained processes of workers?

Comment: Not sure about resources. But I would recommend to read and understand about Nginx, Unicorn and resque workers in their master site. That much solve the issue.